# Disable links to images only if link is pointing to an image for Wordpress site

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, image, function

I'm looking for a code to put in my custom-functions.php that will only disable the links to images that link to an image (jpg, jpeg, png, gif, ect.)

I used this code provided from this page: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33724/remove-links-from-images-using-functions-php

This is the code I inserted in my custom-functions.php

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'attachment_image_link_remove_filter' );

function attachment_image_link_remove_filter( $content ) {
    $content =
        preg_replace(
            array('{<a(.*?)(wp-att|wp-content\/uploads)[^>]*><img}',
                '{ wp-image-[0-9]*" /></a>}'),
            array('<img','" />'),
            $content
        );
    return $content;
}
```

but it is too robust and disabled every link that is wrapped around an image. I still want links to work that point to pages, posts, pdfs, docs.

Could any of you help?

Thank you kindly.

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)